# How do I convert HTML tag to Rails tags?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I've been breaking my head to get this working in Rails file tag. I just want to make a file field accept multiple files. For that I need the name to be "attachment[]" instead of "attachment". But for the life of me, I can not figure this out.

How do I convert this simple HTML?

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="folderinput" multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
```

I have this,

```
<%= file_field_tag :attachment, multiple: true, id: "folderinput", style: "display:none;", "webkitdirectory"=> "", "directory"=> "" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing `:attachment` by `"attachment[]"`?

```
<%= file_field_tag "attachment[]", multiple: true, id: "folderinput", style: "display:none;", "webkitdirectory"=> "", "directory"=> "" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<%= file_field_tag "attachment", multiple: true, id: "folderinput",name: "attachment[]", style: "display:none;", "webkitdirectory"=> "", "directory"=> "" %>`